# iOS: Autolayout: Lock new position after animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I tried to write a category function for UIView that will get the constraints that will hold an given frame in place in its superview. I implemented it like so:

```
    -(NSArray *)constraintsForLockingPositionInSuperview
    {
        NSLayoutConstraint *left=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:0 constant:self.frame.origin.x];

        NSLayoutConstraint *height=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:Nil 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:self.frame.size.height];

        NSLayoutConstraint *width=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:Nil 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:self.frame.size.width];

        NSLayoutConstraint *top=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:0 constant:self.frame.origin.y];

        return @[left,height,width,top  ];

    }
```

And then after animating the view, apply to new constraints by doing the following in the view controller that contains the view in question. I remove the view then re-add it to remove the constraints that were on it, then reapply the new constraints. The hope was that this would hold the view in place if I add another subview or if something like an actionView comes in and the view has to layout itself out. The height and the width seem to be locking properly, but the view is jumping to the middle instead of locking in place:

```
NSArray *lockingConstraints = [someView constraintsForLockingPositionInSuperview];
        [someView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:someView;
        [self.view addConstraints:lockingConstraints];
        [self.view layoutSubviews];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [layoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews):

> You should not call this method directly.

Call [layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutIfNeeded) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will definitely not call it directly anymore. But, layoutIfNeeded didn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked! I forgot that I had changed in the anchorpoint in my animation. When I got rid of that statement, it worked! Any idea why thats the case?